# Hadoop '-classpath' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, hadoop, classpath

I'm trying to install hadoop on my computer (Windows 10, 64 bit) but when I go to test if it installed, I keep getting the error:

**'-classpath' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

I have no idea why this is happening. I thought my system variables were set correctly but apparently not. I was just wondering if anyone could tell me what is going on with this -classpath stuff. Below is a snapshot of the error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhMQo.png)

And here are further images of my stem and path variables. As well as a snapshot of the bin directory in hadoop.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2O3O.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAiPu.png)

Comment: Hi there! It is easier for everyone if you post the text straight, instead of images of text.

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that `%JAVA_HOME%` included a space in the path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191`. After changing it to `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_191` it started to work.
So check that all the relevant *env* variables (Java, Hadoop) are defined without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with your path . Your path contains some spaces. Just remove the spaces .
Suppose any folder name in your path is like

> Hadoop folder

You can clearly see the space in your folder name in your path so you just rename the folder name as

> Hadoopfolder

Or

> Hadoop-folder

Just rename it everywhere and try to install it again .